# OpenGL muliply/add texture with glColor

Tags: java, opengl, sprite, lwjgl

I'm making a game in Java using the LWJGL and Slick.

From what I understand glColor multiplies the RGB values, but what if I wanted to add color to a texture that's had RBG removed? (desaturated)

The purpose of this is to create a grey texture and then use OpenGL to add color to it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding is most likely not what you wan't. Adding is more of a brightening effect.

It sounds like the feature that you wan't is multiplying (glColor). If you have a grayscale texture, mulyiplying it with a color like red will create an image where the white parts of the texture are pure red, and the dark sections are darker shades of red.

Read:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes

Comment: I've tried using glColor3d and I'm missing something I guess. I'm new to stack overflow and I don't really know how to post. I can put some of my code up on Pastebin or something.

Comment: @JRocha how is what you see different from what you expect?

Comment: The color did not appear to change on the quad, but I changed it to glColor3f and that appears to have worked. Thanks for the help.